# Showing that the graph of a continuous linear mapping is closed if the domain is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, closed-graph

I'm working my way through the book [Introduction to Hilbert Spaces with Applications](https://www.elsevier.com/books/introduction-to-hilbert-spaces-with-applications/debnath/978-0-08-045592-1) and trying to do the exercise of proving a theorem (1.5.11)  (its proof is left as an exercise).

It states that if $L: E_1 \rightarrow E_2$ is a continuous linear mapping, then:

- The nullspace $\mathcal{N}(L)$ is a closed subspace of $E_1$
- If the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ is closed then the graph $\mathcal{G}(L)$ is a closed subspace of $E_1 \times E_2$

The first statement was pretty straight forward, but I'm having a few concerns about my solution (bottom) to the second and would like to ask for help with:

1. How does the choice of norm on $\mathcal{G}(L)$ affects the answer? The book has yet to suggest one for that space and I used an alternative I found elsewhere. But is this statement true regardless of the norm chosen and if so how can I show that?
2. Does my solution look reasonable?

Thanks!

---

Since $E_1$ and $E_2$ were not specified at all I assumed they're both normed spaces for continuity to be definable. Furthermore, given $(x, y) \in E_1 \times E_2$,  I take the norm of $E_1 \times E_2$ to be $||(x, y)||_{1, 2} = ||x||_1 + ||y||_2$.

To prove the statement I took the path of showing that $\mathcal{G}(L)$ is closed by asserting that every sequence $(z_n)$ in $\mathcal{G}(L)$ with $z_n \rightarrow z$, implies $z \in \mathcal{G}(L)$. Take any such sequence. By the definition of the graph, for every $n$ there exists $x_n \in \mathcal{D}(L)$ such that

\begin{equation}
z_n = (x_n, Lx_n)
\end{equation}

Taking $z = (x, \zeta)$ we have $(x_n, Lx_n) \rightarrow (x, \zeta)$, or
\begin{equation}
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } ||(x_n, Lx_n) - (x, \zeta)||_{1, 2} = ||x_n - x||_1 + ||Lx_n - \zeta||_2 < \varepsilon \ \forall \, n \ge N \,.
\end{equation}

This implies $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $Lx_n \rightarrow \zeta$. Since $\mathcal{D}(L)$ closed, $x \in \mathcal{D}(L)$. Also, because $L$ is continuous, $\zeta = Lx$. Therefore, $z \in \mathcal{G}(L)$. $$\tag*{$\Box$}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks good. In regards to the choice of norm on the graph I believe that unless the operator is bounded then the only appropriate (in the sense of convergence) choice of norm is the graph norm itself. Notice that,
\begin{align}
\|x\|_{E_{1}}\leq\|x\|_{E_{1}}+\|Tx\|_{E_{2}}=:\|x\|_{T},
\end{align}
and if $T$ is not bounded then the graph norm is stronger than the norm on $E_{1}$. Now clearly you have that $T$ is bounded, but if $T$ is **not** bounded then convergence in $\|\cdot\|_{E_{1}}$ implies nothing about convergence in $\|\cdot\|_{T}$.

As you may have worked out however, is if $T$ is bounded then $\|\cdot\|_{E_{1}}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{T}$ are **equivalent** norms. In which case if,
\begin{align}
\|x_{n}-x\|_{E_{1}}\to0,
\end{align}
then,
\begin{align}
\|Tx_{n}-\zeta\|_{E_{2}}\to0.
\end{align}

The point here is that what you have shown ($T$ continuous $\implies$ graph$(T)$ closed) is in fact an if and only if statement (please do not take what I have written to be a proof, it is not).